# Using iTextSharp's PdfStamper to fill particular Imported Pages and append to a new Pdf

Tags: itext

I'm trying to import pages one by one from a 2-page pdf, fill them up with pre-defined data and then finally save pdf to the disk after form flattening. However, I'm not sure about the usage of PdfStamper in here. Could anyone please help ? Please see the sample code below. Here I'm not sure about lines in bold (between **s).

```
while (i < n)
            {
                i++;
                document.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i));
                document.NewPage();
                page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                **var ms = new MemoryStream();
                PdfReader pr = new PdfReader(page.ToPdf(writer).ToArray());
                var stamper = new PdfStamper(pr, ms);
                stamper.AcroFields.SetField("payrollNo", "666666");
                stamper.Close();**
                rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(i);
                if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270)
                {
                    cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Height);
                }
                else
                {
                    cb.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
                }
            }
```

Thanks ahead !

Answer (score 2):

This will solve your problem:

```
    static PdfReader GetPdf(string filename, bool FillForm)
    {
        PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(filename);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader2, ms);
            var form = stamper.AcroFields;
            var fieldKeys = form.Fields.Keys;

            if (FillForm)
            foreach (string fieldKey in fieldKeys)
                form.SetField(fieldKey, "REPLACED!");

            stamper.Writer.CloseStream = false; 
            stamper.FormFlattening = true;
            stamper.Close();
            reader2.Close();

            return new PdfReader(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
```